# converting from h265 to h264 10bit created audio quality issues

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, codec, h.265

The following code was saved as a batch file and run locally in a folder that had a season worth of files that i needed converted to H.264.

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a aac -b:a 128k "newfiles\%%~na.mp4" pause
```

Input Video Codec: MPEG-H Part2/HEVC (H.265) (hevc)
Input Audio Codec: MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a)
Sample rate: 48000 Hz
Bits per sample: 32

Video quality was what I expected but the audio quality declined to a tinny echo-like quality. I'm thinking my problem might be with the "-b:a 128k" but dont know audio codecs nor FFMPEG well enough (read: at all) to know how to fix or tinker.

Disclaimer: reasons for converting to h.264 was due to lack of h.265 support on the raspberry pi. I have successfully converted these files since this issue occurred with Handbrake, but i want to know what might've happened with FFMPEG.

Comment: Since input is already AAC, no need to re-encode audio. Replace `-c:a aac` with `-c:a copy`

Comment: for cases like mine, when i just need to get the format from h.265 to h.264 due to hardware constraints, is there a different angle i should be taking this problem?